# Index no result when keyword contains mutated vowel (umlaut)

Tags: c#, sitecore, lucene.net

I have a weird behavior on a customer environment. We have setup a `Lucene` index with `Sitecore`. When searching the index with a keyword that contains mutated vowels (umlaute, such as `äöü`, e.g. `Zürich`) no results are returned even though there are some. On our environments this works just fine. The configuration and setup of the solution is the same on both systems as far as I can tell.

I've looked at both indexes with `Luke`. They seem to be the same as well. Searching with a keyword containing mutated vowels returned the same results with `Luke`. So the indexing itself should be fine just the querying seems to be different.

I'm thinking there must be a config / installation missing on the operating system or maybe `IIS` itself, or what else could cause this?

Does anyone have a similar experience?

Thanks,
Serge

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Solr & Lucence, turned out in the customer environment i had to add URIEncoding="UTF-8" to the "Connector"  node in the following config file.

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\server.xml

Yours may not be the exact same issue, but i would look into character encoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on with your customer's environment, however, the solution below may come in handy for this issue as well as others that can stem from searching for words with special characters.

The following method will strip any diacritical marks from a string of text. For example, if you pass it `Zürich` it will return `Zurich`. The trick is to pass your content through this method prior to indexing. In Sitecore 6 this can be done in a custom implementation of a DatabaseCrawler. In Sitecore 7, a computed field might be a good candidate.

```
public static string NormalizeDiacritics(this string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return String.Empty;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD))
    {
        if (char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The next step is to also pass the visitor's search queries through the same method. This way, you can be assured that a search for either `Zürich` or `Zurich` will always return results. This is especially handy because many visitors don't take the time to enter special characters when searching online (at least this is true for English speaking visitors).